# Is calling AttributeSet.recycle() from a finally clause an Android anti-pattern?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I see this "pattern" used in Android custom `View`s a lot (including the SDK docs):

```
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.PieChart,
        0, 0);

   try {
       mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieChart_showText, false);
       mTextPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PieChart_labelPosition, 0);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
```

I know it's important to always recycle an `AttributeSet`, but is the `finally` really necessary? I checked the docs and the only exception that can possibly be thrown in the `try` block above will only happen if `a` is `null` or if `a` is already recycled, in which case we don't want to call `recycle()` anyway.

Aside from the possibility of adding more code in the future that could throw a different exception, is there any reason to use the `try/finally` block?

Comment: I've edited towards that end myself, but going forward -- please try to make a title specific enough that someone can know what the potential anti-pattern (or other thing being asked about) is from that title alone. Using "this" obligates people to click through to learn more.

Comment: It is possible that "a" has NULL value, so you will get an NullPointerException. However this is not the right way to use try..finally block. You have to declare "a" outside of the try..finally block and then assign "a = context.getTheme..." AT THE BEGINNING of it. If you use your code and that line generates an exception it will not trigger the FINALLY part and the method exits prematurely due to this Exception.

Comment: @emandt If "a" is null, I don't want to call a.recycle() so a NullPointerException doesn't matter. If any of the calls to assign "a" throw an exception, I also don't need to call a.recycle() in the finally, so i don't need to call them in the try. In other words I still don't see any need for the try/finally.

Comment: But if the Exception is thrown INSIDE the try..finally block the method could ends normally. Instead if the Exception occurs OUTSIDE it that method makes the App to crash (if you don't manage that Exception in the Caller method using another try..catch block).

Comment: True, but they we only need the try block, not the finally block. a.recycle() can just go at the bottom.

Comment: Also, the app will crash whether the exeception happens inside or outside the try block because try doesn't catch exceptions, only catch does.